# Como insertar un objecto en una lista enlazada creada dinamicamente c++

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda de como insertar una clase en una lista enlazada, tengo que crear una lista donde se crea un restaurente, ahi tengo que  insertar un menu ya creado, como podria hacer eso?, les muestro el codigo
void registrar_restaurante(PListaR &lista){

```
PListaR t,q = new(struct nodoR);

cout<<"\n\n\t\t[  Registro  ]\n";
cout<<"\t\t------------";
cout<<"\n\tDatos del Restaurante";
cin.ignore();cout<<"\n\n\tCedula Juridica:"; cin>>q->codigo;
cin.ignore();cout<<"\n\tNombre:"; cin.getline(q->nombres,maxchar);
cin.ignore();cout<<"\tTipo de Comida:"; cin.getline(q->tipoComida,maxchar);
cin.ignore();cout<<"\n\tventa:"; cin>>q->venta;
system("cls");
//q->nodoRPediddo = NULL;
q->sgte = NULL;


if(lista==NULL){
    
    lista = q;
    
} else {
    
    t = lista;
    
    while(t->sgte!=NULL){
        
        t = t->sgte;
    }
    
    t->sgte = q;
    
}
```

}
void registrar_restaurante(PListaP &lista){

```
PListaP t,q = new(struct nodoPediddo);
int n []= {4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000};
int aux = 0;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t[  Agregar Pedido  ]\n";
cout<<"\t\t------------";
cout<<"\n\tDatos del Menu";
for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
{
    cout<<"N"<<(0+1)<<" valor: "<<n[i]<<endl;
}
Pedido objTemp;
cout<<"Seleccione un menu: _\b";
cin>>aux;
    objTemp.setcombo(aux);
cout<<"Cantidad de combos: _\b";
cin>>aux;

    objTemp.setCantCombos(aux);
objTemp.setCantPagar(n[objTemp.getcombo()-1]*aux);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar definir la estructura que vas a usar para almacenar los datos del restaurante y los pedidos. Necesitaremos mínimo un puntero al primer pedido de la lista, con uno al último será más fácil añadir. Además dentro del "nodoRestaurante" tendremos también un puntero al siguiente restaurante. Algo como:

```
struct Restaurante{
  string nombre;
  int id;

  Reastaurante* sigRestaurante;

  Pedido* primerPedido;
  Pedido* ultimoPedido;

};
```

Después necesitaremos también la estructura Pedido, en la que tendremos un puntero al siguiente pedido.

```
struct Pedido{
  string nombre;
  Pedido* sigPedido = NULL;
};
```

Ahora desde nuestro **main**

```
int main() {
 // Asignamos dinámicamente memoria para nuestras estructuras
 Restaurante* r = (Restaurante*)malloc(sizeof(Restaurante));
 Pedido* m = (Pedido*)malloc(sizeof(Menu));
 
 // El primer pedido añadido será el primero y último
 r->primerPedido = m;
 r->ultimoPedido = m;

 // Ahora cada vez que queramos añadir un pedido nuevo al restaurante "r"
 Pedido* nodoPedido = (Pedido*)malloc(sizeof(Pedido));
 (r->ultimoPedido)->sigPedido = nodoPedido;
 r->ultimoPedido = nodoPedido;
}
```

Date cuenta que lo que necesitas, si entiendo bien tu problema, son realmente dos listas enlazadas.
**Una lista de restaurantes, donde cada restaurante tiene una lista de pedidos**